# Can't replace all occurrence character with regexp until unique character?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace if string is started with `/` until next unique character ... I tried like below , but it replace all occurrences into one only ! I want to replace all occurrence characters ...

```js
var textTitle = "///test///";
var result = textTitle.replace(/^\/{1,}/g, '../');
console.log(result); // wanted => ../../../test///

textTitle = "//test/";
result = textTitle.replace(/^\/{1,}/g, '../');
console.log(result); // wanted => ../../test/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `y` flag which takes one step on each successful approach on `lastIndex` property:

```js
console.log("///test///".replace(/\//gy, "../"));
```

Comment: What will be opposite way to do !! `g?` [just want to know]

Comment: If you mean doing from the end you are in need of a positive lookahead: `"///test///".replace(/\/(?=[\/]*$)/g, "../");` @DavidJorHpan

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
var textTitle = "///test///";
var result = textTitle.replace(/^\/{1,}/g, (match, key) => {
    return match.split('').reduce((res, next) => res += '..' + next, '');

});
console.log(result);
```

```js
var textTitle = "///test///";
    var result = textTitle.replace(/^\/{1,}/g, (match, key) => {
        return match.split('').reduce((res, next) => res += '..' + next, '');

    });
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: why you use `, '' ` in reduce function ! Can you explain a little ?